# Lambda S3 getObject (fired from ajax call) throws 403 denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which gets an image from one bucket, resizes it and puts it into another bucket. The lambda function is set to trigger when a file is created the source bucket. Fairly standard, tutorial level stuff.

When I use the aws web UI to put an image in the source bucket, everything works as expected.

However, when I use xhr from my web app to put an image into the same bucket, I get the following error (thrown from my s3.getObject call):

```
AccessDenied: Access Denied
at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35
```

Having extensively searched around, most folk are saying 403 errors usually boil down to role/policy permissions for the lambda function. But when I trawl the logs, the only difference I see between my xhr upload and an aws web UI upload is the eventName and userIdentity.

For a web UI upload it's Put and principalId:

```
eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put',
userIdentity: { principalId: 'AWS:AIDAJ2VMZPNX5NJD2VBLM' }
```

But on a xhr call it's Post and Anonymous:

```
eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Post',
userIdentity: { principalId: 'Anonymous' }
```

My Lambda role has two policies attached:

AWSLambdaExecute

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My S3 buckets have the following policies:

Source bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Lambda access bucket policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "All on objects in bucket lambda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket-name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "All on bucket by lambda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::source-bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Destination bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Lambda access bucket policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "All on objects in bucket lambda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket-name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "All on bucket by lambda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to somehow pass (or assign) a Principal Id to my xhr call to get it to work? Or do I need to add permissions/policies/roles to my function to let it fire the function without a Principal Id attached to the trigger?

EDIT:
Here's the JS code that sends a POST'ed file to the source bucket:

```
function uploadFileAttachment(attachment, form) {

  var formButtons = document.querySelectorAll("form.form--trix button.btn");

  formButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  });

  uploadFile(attachment.file, setProgress, setAttributes)

  function setProgress(progress) {
    attachment.setUploadProgress(progress)
  }

  function setAttributes(attributes) {

    attachment.setAttributes(attributes)

    formButtons.forEach((button) => {
      button.removeAttribute("disabled");
    });

  }
}

function uploadFile(file, progressCallback, successCallback) {

  var key = createStorageKey(file)
  var formData = createFormData(key, file)
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhr.open("POST", global.s3url, true)

  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
    var progress = event.loaded / event.total * 100
    progressCallback(progress)
  })

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    if (xhr.status == 204) {
      var attributes = {
        url: global.s3url + key,
        href: global.s3url + key + "?content-disposition=attachment"
      }
      successCallback(attributes)
    }
  })

  xhr.send(formData);
}

function createStorageKey(file) {
  var date = new Date()
  var day = date.toISOString().slice(0,10)
  var name = date.getTime() + "-" + file.name
  return [ "trix", day, name ].join("/")
}

function createFormData(key, file) {
  var data = new FormData()
  data.append("key", key)
  data.append("Content-Type", file.type)
  data.append("file", file)
  return data
}
```

Comment: Can you share the ajax code as well ?

Comment: @AmitBaranes I've just edited my question to add the JS.